# Proving $\frac{(2\cos^2 x - 1)^2}{\cos^4 x - \sin^4 x} = 1 - 2 \sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that 
$$\frac{(2\cos^2 x - 1)^2}{\cos^4 x - \sin^4 x} = 1 - 2 \sin^2x$$

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your work and where you faced problems

Comment: Are you able to solve now? Or are you still facing problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$2\cos^{2}{(x)} - 1 = \cos{(2x)} = \cos^{2}{(x)} -\sin^{2}{(x)}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, $(\cos 2x)^2/\cos 2x=\cos 2x$, where one of the three famous expressions for $\cos 2x$ has been multiplied by $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ to throw you off the scent. (As @OscarLanzi points out, we could instead think of them as three expressions for $\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ if we didn't know double angle formulae.)

Comment: You don't need the double angle formulas at all.  _They_ throw the scent off in this problem.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks; edited.

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is $(\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x)(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)$. 
Furthermore, you should know something about  $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x$...

Answer (score 0):

1. Factor $\cos^4 x-\sin^4 x=(\cos^2 x)^2-(\sin^2 x)^2$ as a difference of squares.
2. Render $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x = 1$ to eliminate the cosine terms.
3. Everything falls into place.